# Overall (not daily) limit for reputation gained from answer

Tags: support, reputation, limits

Is there any overall limit for reputation that can be gained from answer?

I've been [awarded bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669808/480199) (+400) and since then I get no additional reputation points for upvotes on that answer. When I try to debug the situation ( https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ) I get strange 0pt daily summary entries, e.g.:

```
-- 2012-09-05 rep +10   = 1338      
-- 2012-09-20 rep 0     = 1338      
-- 2012-09-26 rep 0     = 1338      
-- 2012-09-30 rep 0     = 1338      
-- 2012-10-01 rep 0     = 1338      
-- 2012-10-06 rep 0     = 1338      
 2  11645436 (10)
-- 2012-10-09 rep +10   = 1348      
-- 2012-10-10 rep 0     = 1348      
 16 12771214 (2)
-- 2012-10-14 rep +2    = 1350      
-- 2012-10-15 rep 0     = 1350      
-- 2012-10-16 rep 0     = 1350      
 2  11544096 (10)
 16  8998973 (2)
-- 2012-10-18 rep +12   = 1362      
 2  11367895 (10)
-- 2012-10-19 rep +10   = 1372      
-- 2012-10-27 rep 0     = 1372      
 2  13183318 (10)
 2  13202720 (10)
 1  13202720 (15)
-- 2012-11-02 rep +35   = 1407      
-- 2012-11-06 rep 0     = 1407
```

I think that these entries occur on days when I get upvote for my answer. However, I'm not 100% sure (but somewhere around 80%) as I haven't monitored the upvotes each day. There's no way to determine dates, because there's no trace of these in my event logs on SO.

Are there any limits that I run into here or maybe this is some kind of SO error?

Comment: You can flag the answer and request un-community-wikification. That wish may be granted (or declined).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the hint. I did that. Waiting for the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Your answer has become a community wiki because you have edited it 10 times.

Since it's a wiki, you no longer gain or lose rep for votes on it. But you will still receive rep from bounties that get awarded to it.

---

The 10-edit threshold is to prevent abusive bumping which probably isn't the case here. You can flag to see if a mod is willing to unwiki it for you.

But for future reference, try to merge as many edits together and do them all at once. Consider yourself lucky that this hit you on a post with only 24 votes.

Comment: Well, he got the rep for these 24 votes, that's the (many or not) future ones that won't get counted which make him lucky (or not).

Comment: Either way, it's still nothing compared to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/922184). That IMO, is the biggest victim of wiki. But because it was wikied so long ago, SE policy prevents it from being unwikied.

Comment: In any case, I regularly patrol the highest voted posts on the site and flag them out of wiki as soon as I discover one that is wikied from edits. I'm *not* a fan of auto-wiki.

Comment: @Mysticial Great answer, the matter got less mystical :) Unfortunately, I didn't get any rep points from this answer for a long time (10th revision was submitted by the end of July), so I lost somewhere around 140 reputation points ;/ I wonder if they get automatically counted in back if the answer is unwikied...

Comment: @Mysticial And thanks for your community work on flagging answers out of wiki. I'm sure many appreciate it.

Comment: Just to close the issue: my answer got unwikied by moderator, and I've been awarded all lost reputation points.